# C++, ostream &sout=name.empty() ? cout : ofstream(name); example for beginners?

Tags: ostream

So the teacher gave us this video, I copied the code, I have been working on it for days, researching, and still have no idea what is that all about?
https://youtu.be/DdSvGeJZAyo?t=519

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {


string name;


cout << "write your name  " << endl;

cin>> name;

ostream &sout=name.empty() ? 
cout : ofstream(name);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It uses the [ternary operator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to assign one of two values to a variable. It is equivalent to:

```
if (name.empty())
  sout = cout;
else
  sout = ofstream(name);
```

The reason for the use of the ternary operator instead of the `if` is that `sout` is a **reference**, which must be associated with an existing object when it is created. That is, you cannot declare a reference and then assign its referrent later.

Both `std::cout` and `std::ofstream`s are descendents of `std::ostream`, so you can use `sout` as an output stream without caring whether it is actually the terminal or a file.

The given code is in error, though, because it creates a reference to a *temporary object*. Once the statement is done the newly opened file is closed and the file object is destroyed, leaving a dangling reference -- something that C++ makes difficult but not impossible. Your compiler should have complained.